# Where is the runuser command on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

When I type in my console "runuser", I am getting "command not found". I though this command was pretty standard, but I cannot find it on my system.

I am on the root user but I do not have the password of the other user.

Comment: Please justify when you click on "-1" on a question. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't downvote this (yet), but if you mouse over the down arrowhead, it says "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  If a downvote appears without further comment, you may reasonably assume that that's what the voter thought of your question.

Comment: `runuser` is intended for use by system services which need to [change UID and preserve their SELinux security contexts](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/55588.html). This is not a command that you should be running yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment on the other answer:

> When I do `su - otheruser`, I am getting `No directory, logging in with HOME=/`. Then when I run `whoami`, I get `root`.

This happens because 'otheruser' hasn't got a shell (like bash). It's probably something like /bin/false. If you want a shell as 'otheruser', use this instead:

```
sudo -u otheruser /bin/bash
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the main question.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu you have `su` and `sudo` for this sort of thing:

```
su - username
```

Changes to user `username`, as if that user had logged in.

```
sudo -u username command
```

Run a single command as user `username`.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am looking for the runuser function because I do not have the password for the other user.

Comment: You don't need the password if you set up `sudoers`.

Comment: When I do "su - otheruser", I am getting "No directory, logging in with HOME=/". Then when I run "whoami", I get "root".

Comment: `No directory, logging in with HOME=/` is normal if the user has no home directory assigned or the directory doesn't exist. How you get `root` from `whoami` is beyond me.

Comment: Yes, the error message is normal. It is the whoami which I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

[It is in the util-linux package](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/runuser.1.html), so if you want it, install that package.